# ListView - on scroll select all list items

Tags: android, listview, scroll

When I scroll my custom ListView without using scollbars, it selects all items. How could I prevent that effect and why this is happening?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try a image in background of row, may it solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it works, but in my **ListView** each item is generated dynamically and wraps the content inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you select all your items.
You should try to set for your ListView in the xml:

```
    android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
```

See [ListView cacheColorHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint) .